# Have to reinstall DirectX every time I start my PC

Tags: directx

Recently, every time I restart my computer I have been getting this error message:

> ksbsync.exe
>
> This program cannot start because OpenCLD.dll is missing.

This seems to prevent games from running. If I reinstall DirectX and my Graphics card drivers they work again. Does anyone have an idea of what could be causing this problem every time I restart?

I'm running Windows 7 with an AMD Redeon HD 6700 Graphics card.

Comment: Have you tried reinstall amd radeon drivers?

Comment: Yep, sorry should have said originally.

Comment: @AdamUlivi - What version of DirectX are you install exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Never found a solution. The problem seemed to get worse and there was a start-up error every time I tried to restart. Tried restore points and turning off updates but nothing worked. In the end I had to format the hard drive and do a fresh install.